# Pause MediaPlayer when the view becomes invisible

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, visibility, android-custom-view

I work on some Android custom view, based on TextureView and MediaPlayer. I want to pause MediaPlayer when TextureView is invisible. I tried to do it in the next way:

override `onVisibilityChanged()` and `onDetachedFromWindow()` in the root layout of my custom View. It works ok, except 2 cases:

- start new activity that hides my TextureView, it works  but with delay few seconds, until new Activity is fully loaded
- lock device by power button

In this 2 cases MediaPlayer continue to work in background.
How to pause MediaPlayer when the view becomes invisible without overriding Acitivity `onResume()`, `onPause()` methods?

**UPD** - code sample

```
public class MyCustomView extends FrameLayout {

    private VisibilityListener visibilityListener;

    public interface VisibilityListener {
        void onVisibilityChanged(int visibility);
    }

    protected void onVisibilityChanged(View changedView, int visibility) {
        super.onVisibilityChanged(changedView, visibility);
        if (visibilityListener != null) {
            visibilityListener.onVisibilityChanged(visibility);
        }
    }

    public void setVisibilityListener(VisibilityListener visibilityListener) {
        if (visibilityListener != null) {
            this.visibilityListener = visibilityListener;
        }
    }

    protected void onDetachedFromWindow() {
        super.onDetachedFromWindow();
        if (visibilityListener != null) {
            visibilityListener.onVisibilityChanged(INVISIBLE);
        }
    }

}
```

And how I use it:

```
        public void onVisibilityChanged(int visibility) {
            if (mediaPlayer == null) {
                return;
            }
            try {
                if (visibility == View.VISIBLE) {
                    mediaPlayer.start();
                } else {
                    mediaPlayer.pause();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "mediaPlayer issue", e);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Why don't you want to override onResume() or onPause() methods?

Comment: Also, put your current code state if possible

Comment: @user3793589 I want to make the component which other people will use, and make it integration as simple as possible, so, if its possible to handle visibility changes by view itself - it is much preferably.